# invariants of group action by algebra automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I am trying to prove the following statement, but I'm having a lot of trouble with it:

> Let $k$ be an infinite field. Let $A$ be a commutative $k$-algebra. Let $G$, a group, act on $A$ by algebra automorphism. Assume that $A$ is completely decomposable, that is $A=\bigoplus_{i\in I} L_i$ for $L_i$ irreducible subrepresentations. Then:
>   (a) For $J:=\{i\in I: L_i\cong k\}$ we have $A^G=\bigoplus_{j\in J}L_j$, where $k$ is the trivial representation of $G$.
>   (b) Write $N:=\bigoplus_{i\in I\backslash J}L_i$, thus $A=A^G\oplus N$. Let $\pi: A\to A^G$ be the projection along this decomposition. Then $\pi(hf)=h\pi(f)$ for $h\in A^G, f\in A$.

What I have so far:
(a) "$\supseteq$" is clear by definition. We can write $a\in A^G$ uniquely as a direct sum $a=\sum_{i\in I'} a_i$ (for $I'\subseteq I$ finite). Now $a\in A^G$ says $g.a=a$, thus $\sum_{i\in I'} a_i=a=g.a=\sum_{i\in I'} g.a_i\implies g.a_i=a_i \forall i\in I'$. In particular $G$ acts trivially on all $L_i, i\in I'$ thus $I'=J$ and $a\in\bigoplus_{j\in J}L_j$.

(b) I don't know how to approach this.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Maybe I dont get the question but you have $\pi(hf)=\pi(h)\pi(f)$ and $\pi(h)=h$ since it is projection along a decomposition.

Comment: Yes, I'm very confused by the exercise too, because it basically just is plugging in the definitions.

Comment: Do you agree that my comment solves part b) ?

Comment: Yes I do. I was just asking myself why this is an exercise.

Comment: I think the issue they might want you to consider is how the multiplication of $A$ interacts with the projection $\pi$. To put it another way: the projection $\pi$ is probably defined viewing $A$ as a $G$-module, not a ring. Are you assuming that the projection $\pi$ is an *algebra* homomorphism? If not, how do you know that $\pi(hf) = \pi(h)\pi(f)$?

Comment: @Dan: Even if we didn't assume $\phi$ was an algebra homomorphism, isn't this still quite clear(?): Let's assume we have the invariant summands at the "beginning" of the direct sum and the projection is just "forgetting" the summands of $N$. Let $h=\sum_{i\in I} h_i, f=\sum_{i\in I} f_i$, where $h$ is invariant, $f$ is not. By (a) we see that $\phi(h)=h$. Now multiplication is defined by $hf=\sum_{i\in I} h_i*f_i$. Since $h_i=0$ for $i\in I\backslash J$ we have that $hf=\sum_{j\in J} h_j*f_j$ thus $\pi(hf)=h\pi(f)$. I guess they wanted us to look at the technicalities involved?

Comment: @blst: You're on the right track. Do you know that the multiplication in $A$ respects the direct sum decomposition? Why did you write $hf = \sum_{i \in I}h_if_i$ as opposed to $hf = \sum_{i,j \in I}h_i f_j$? If you write $f = f_J + f'$ with $f_J = \pi(f) \in A^G$ and $f' \in N$, then $\pi(hf) = \pi(hf_J) + \pi(hf')$ is true, and they want you to show that $\pi(hf) = hf_J$. Is it true that $\pi(hf') = 0$ and $\pi(hf_J) = hf_J$? My point is that (based on what's mentioned in the problem/your solution so far) it's unclear how $\pi$, $A^G$, and $N$ are affected by multiplication in the algebra.

Comment: @Dan: I see, I was assuming it was okay to use that if we have the direct sum of algebras $X,Y$, then we have $(x_1+y_1)*(x_2+y_2)=(x_1*x_2+y_1*y_2)$. But considering your approach: $\pi(hf_J)=hf_J$ since $hf_J\in A^G$ ($G$ acts by automorphism). And $\pi(hf')=0$ since $g.(hf')=(g.h)(g.f')=h*g.f'\neq h*f'$ since $f'\in N$ and again because $G$ acts by automorphism.

Comment: @blst: Good! Yeah that's what I had in mind. It's always good to check this sort of thing explicitly when you're encountering it for the first time (or at least when it's new to you). You should answer your own question and then accept your answer! `:D`